# matching an exact .htaccess url (making it so if URL is longer then it isnt in effect)

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule which is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/whats-news/$ http://www.example.com/index.php/whats-news [R=301]
```

what I want to happen is if the user goes to www.example.com/whats-news then they are taken to www.example.com/index.php/whats-news BUT if they go to www.example.com/whats-news/admin.php then it shouldn't rewrite the url to be www.example.com/index.php/whats-news/admin.php.

but my current rule doesn't even work to redirect? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?(whats-news)/?$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi! this worked, I will accept when I can - I would just like to know, would this rewriterule mean that only /whats-news is redirected to index.php/whats-news?

Because I don't want to append index.php to anything but whats-news.

Comment: You see that's not really what I asked for, I want it to affect just /whats-news
so I want it to NOT affect anything that isn't /whats-news

Comment: So not affecting anything with a DOT is too broad.